# Is the D in words like Fridge and Bridge silent?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, silent-letters

The other day, I was discussing the pronunciation of *fridge* with friends on a social media group. They insisted that the *d* in *fridge* is completely silent. Is that so? I have always said it with a slight *d* sound. Which is correct?

Comment: Where are your friends from?

Comment: We're all in India.

Comment: It's silent the way the first 't' in *letter* is silent.

Comment: Or more accurately, the way that the 't' in *batch* is silent.

Comment: I'm wondering if the friends are thinking that if neither d or g were silent, fri**dg**e would be pronounced similar to hea**dg**ear (i.e. two distinct consonant sounds, "frid-guh"). it's not the case, but can explain their reasoning as to why they consider one of the consonants to be silent in order to avoid having to say "frid-guh".

Comment: It's rather that *fringe* or *gel* are pronounced with an imagined *d* :-).

Comment: @Dan. If I may ask for a clarification, are you saying the t in batch is completely silent? Or the way I say it, with a hint of that t ?

Comment: @MohanSivanand: I'm saying that the "ch" sound, being an affricate /t͡ʃ/, already starts off as a /t/ sound.  The grapheme "tch" is thus phonetically "redundant", except that it disambiguates *batch* from *Bach*.

Comment: @Dan except that the "a" in "batch" is not the same sound as the "a" in "Bach".

Comment: @Michael except in New Zealand English, where a bach is a holiday home (homonym with batch)

Comment: @llama right, but I was playing off the fact that "Bach" was capitalized implying a proper noun :-)

Comment: I have problems even imagining how you would pronounce it without a "d" sound. Like Frish?

Comment: @PeterShor Well [Django](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ci4g8D5wSww) deemed important to mention that in his name, the *D* is silent

Comment: @PeterShor I thought it was the second "t" that was silent?  :-)

Comment: @PBarryYoung. It took me a few seconds to realize that PeterShor was joking. A similar thing happened at a friend's editorial department. There was a typo—an extra C—in a headline that said AICCC (a known political party abbreviation here in India). A proofreader pointed that out to an editor. "Now which C should I remove?" asked the editor.

Answer (score 66):

First, we must distinguish spelling from pronunciation. As we all know, there are words that have excess letters (e.g., "though") or inconsistent letters ("jump" but "ginger", "height" but "fight"). So we can't really operate on the principle that English spelling is a 1-to-1 mapping of letters to sounds.

In this case, it's best to think of "dg" making a single sound, just as "th" and "sh", do. It's not that "th" can be decomposed into a "t" part and an "h" part. You'll find that pronouncing those two sounds in sequence does *not* produce the same sound as in "th". So it's probably best to treat "dg" the same way, and consider it to be an idiosyncratic way to spell the affricate sound we represent with /dʒ/ in IPA (usually often ligatured to indicate that it's one flowing sound).

Another angle is to consider alternatives. If it were spelled "frige", you might expect it to have the same vowel as in "site", not as in "sit". You might propose "frij", but we don't allow j's at the end of words in English, except in foreign words like Hajj. And if it was just "frig", you'd expect it to be pronounced like "sprig", with a so-called hard G. Thus it's likely that the spellers of English chose "dg" to be a double consonant to indicate that the vowel beforehand is short. They may have also chosen it to contrast with French, where "g" is a kind of "zh" sound as in "pleasure". Why not go with "gg"? It was actually common in the Middle Ages, but fell out of style. There's not a lot of strong logic to some of the decisions that were made in the standardization of English spelling.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I gather there is a D involved.

Comment: That's right: [English has a many-to-many bidirectional mapping between letters and sounds](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/pronunciation-vs-spelling/info), and neither need be just one unit at a time either because sometimes several letters together map to just one or another sound, but other times it's several sounds together that map to just one or another letter. Or worse.

Comment: For words spelled similarly without the "d", all I can think of is "oblige", which is pronounced completely differently.

Comment: Also [Rigel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigel) is apparently pronounced with /aɪd͡ʒ/ by most English speakers. But my intuition for "frige" would have rather been /fɹɪɡə/ free-guh, similar to _rigour_.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Many, many, MANY words written with ‹g› have a  /d/ in them, far more than you can ever count: *allergy, gist, surgeon, logic, forge, George, sage, rage, page, region, legion, giant, outrage, frigid, magic, umbrage, origin,  savage, gin, Belgium, giraffe, biology, biologist, ravage, cogitate, register, engine, energy, ginger, Glaswegian, legible, Marge, digit, oxygen, nitrogen,  pelagic, gauge, privilege, refuge*. The list goes ever on and on. For exceptions where the /d/ is silent look to French imports like *beige* and *mirage*.

Comment: @tchrist I was looking specifically for words ending in "-ige" which seems less common.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman *Oblige* has a /d/ in it, doesn't it?

Comment: @tchrist Maybe, depending on your dialect.  But it's never *spelled* with a "d".  And I think the change in vowel sound has a significant effect on that.  Point being that if you took the letter "d" out of "fridge" or "midge" or "cartridge" etc., it would more likely be pronounced like "oblige" with a long "i".

Comment: *Pigeon* and *widgeon* suggest to me that it's a bit pointless looking for rules here.

Comment: See also badge and wedge, which seem to follow the same principle of keeping the first vowel short.  I'd say it's best to treat English spelling elements as sufficient rather than necessary.  Not all rules apply to all words (often because the words entered the language in different centuries), which is why spelling bees are a thing:  you can't just work backwards from the pronunciation and memorization is involved.  Think French verb conjugation.

Comment: This is just one of the fun and exciting experiences you get when writing a Germanic language with an alphabet originally invented to write Latin.

Comment: *"There's not a lot of strong logic to some of the decisions that were made in the standardization of English spelling."*  -- it appears to have congealed rather than have been standardised. Several times.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Imagine if people took heed of the Orrmulum and we ended up with a system more like Dutch. Alas, what could have been.

Answer (score 43):

Yes, there is a slight d sound in *fridge* and *vestige* just as there is a slight d sound in *legion* but not in *lesion*. In the same way, there is a slight t sound in *which* but not in *wish*. This has nothing to do with the spellings of any of those words.

## *fridge* is /fɻɪd͡ʒ/

It's not really possible to answer your question the way it's asked. That’s because we can only talk about pronunciations in terms of sounds, not letters. So let's talk about the pronunciation.

The pronunciation of *fridge* is /fɻɪd͡ʒ/ in most dialects. That contains the following four phonemes:

1. **/f/**: [voiceless labiodental fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_labiodental_fricative)
2. **/ɻ/**: [voiced retroflex approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_retroflex_approximant)
3. **/ɪ/**: [near-close near-front unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-close_near-front_unrounded_vowel)
4. **/d͡ʒ/**: [voiced palato-alveolar sibilant affricate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_postalveolar_affricate)

Because it's an affricate, that last one isn't really decomposable into two different phonemes, because we don’t think of it that way.  However, both its pieces can occur as distinct phonemes in English, as they do in words like *delusion* and *pleasured*.

## *ridge* is /ɻɪd͡ʒ/

As for *ridge*, that’s got the same three phonemes as *fridge* ends with: /ɻɪd͡ʒ/.

1. **/ɻ/**: [voiced retroflex approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_retroflex_approximant)
2. **/ɪ/**: [near-close near-front unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-close_near-front_unrounded_vowel)
3. **/d͡ʒ/**: [**voiced** palato-alveolar sibilant affricate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_postalveolar_affricate)

## *rich* is /ɻɪt͡ʃ/

But another way to think of *ridge* is that it’s simply the **voiced** version of *rich*, which is /ɻɪt͡ʃ/, now with these three phonemes:

1. **/ɻ/**: [voiced retroflex approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_retroflex_approximant)
2. **/ɪ/**: [near-close near-front unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-close_near-front_unrounded_vowel)
3. **/t͡ʃ/**: [**voiceless** palato-alveolar sibilant affricate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_postalveolar_affricate)

So the only difference between *rich* and *ridge* is that the one ends in the unvoiced version and the other in the voiced version of the same final phoneme, a coärticulated affricate that has two different pieces sounded almost together, ending in a sibilant.

Most speakers will say the /ɻ/ in *rich*, *ridge*, and perhaps *fridge* with a little bit of extra lip-rounding, which phonetically is written [ɻʷ]. But we generally ignore tiny phonetic details like these when trying to explain a word to someone, since it doesn’t change which word people hear said if the lips don’t get rounded for *rich* and *ridge*.

---

#### Joke: *Rich* has a non-silent /t/, *Roger* a non-silent /d/

You should jokingly tell your friends that words like *rich* and *lich* **don't** have a silent /t/ in them — only because in both cases their /t/ sounds are fully audible and not silent at all. :)

This is the same as with the name *Roger*, whose own /d/ sound is **also** completely non-silent because it's also fully audible! So *Roger* has an audible — not a silent! — /d/ in it.

Finally, you can tell them that if they make the /d/ in *legion* silent that they’ll be left with a painful *lesion* instead.

There, that should **really** get them going.

Comment: Thank you, and I like the joke too. But please can you give me a direct answer? Yes or no faint D sound? I've listened to several dictionary audio files and they all say it like I do with a bit of the D sound included? But my friends don't seem to hear that in the same audios. Yet, when they speak, I sense that shadow of a D.

Comment: @MohanSivanand Yes, the /d͡ʒ/ phoneme does start with a "d" sound, then moves quickly to the sibilant sound heard in the middle of *measure, leisure, lesion*. The only difference between *legion* and *lesion* is that "d"  sound in the first of those which is absent in the second of them. The people saying it is not there are focusing on only the sibilant part, but it is easy to get them to hear the difference between minimal pairs like *legion–lesion* where the first has the "d" sound and the second lacks it. Spelling, as you see, has no influence on its presence or absence.

Comment: @MohanSivanand This is exactly the same as when you take a word like *rich, ditch, switch, which*, where you can hear the /t/ sound in all of them at the start of their /t͡ʃ/ phoneme **no matter how they're spelled**. If you remove the /t/ sound, you're left with just the swishy sibilant you hear in words like *dish, wish, swish, fish*.

Comment: Thank you, tchrist. I find that t in your nom de plume equally interesting!

Comment: If I try really hard I can pronounce "legion" without a "d" sound... lee-jun or lee-jin.

Comment: “legion” without a /d/ sound is “lesion”.

Comment: Cutiously, Rodgers is a common surname form, although Rogers also exists, but Rodger as a first name is quite rare.

Comment: It's good to look at the phonetic guide as tchrist pointed out. Just be sure it's the language you are using in that country, US and UK will vary sometimes in pronunciation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing. If you spelled "fridge" as "fridzh", you would pronounce it the same, and the d clearly would not be silent. "Frizh" isn't a word, but it definitely sounds different than "fridzh".

But English doesn't really treat that "dzh" sound as two consecutive consonants. It is just the sound of a so-called "soft g", or, equivalently, the typical sound of a j. Think about "allege", which rhymes with "edge". The "d" sound you hear is there in both words, but there is only a separate "d" in "edge". Personally, I don't think of the "d" as silent in the same sense that the "p" in "psychology" is silent. Instead, I think of its sound as being merged with the beginning of the soft g sound.

Fundamentally, I am saying the same thing as the other answers, but I think some people may be scared off by the IPA, valuable though it is.

Answer (score 0):

The other day, I was discussing the pronunciation of fridge with friends on a social media group. They insisted that the d in fridge is completely silent. Is that so? I have always said it with a slight d sound. Which is correct?

Answer:

You are both correct. Your friends are correct in not hearing an additional “d” sound because both “dge” and “ge” represent the same consonant /d3/ here, so putting a “d” in front of “ge” is redundant here “phonetically” as a “d” sound beginning is already included in /d3/ represented by “ge”.  You are also correct in “hearing” the “d” sound because the “d” sound forms the beginning of the consonant /d3/ (that’s why the creators of the IPA symbols chose the symbol /d3/ to represent this consonant) which is represented by “dge” here in this word.

Comment: So you don't hear a "d" sound because the "d" sound is there in the /d͡ʒ/ sound? I think your first two sentences need revision!

Answer (score -5):

> Is the D in words like Fridge and Bridge silent?

Yes - Frij and Brij would sound the same.